Is it possible to promote by helm release in Argo rollout blue-green deployment?
I'm trying to configure a blue green deployment using argo rollout and helm.
There are two microservices in my project helm file, so there are two rollouts.
/helm/template
- rollout-A.yaml
- rollout-B.yaml
-service-A.yaml
-service-B.yaml
- ingress.yaml

Now I deploy to kubernetes using the command helm upgrade --install MY_HELM_RELEASE MY_HELM_CHART.
Then, there are two rollouts in the argo rollout dashboard.
However, I would like to promote both rollout-A and rollout-B within the helm release at once using only one click or command.
# get all rollout objects in helm release
rollouts=$(kubectl get rollouts -l release=$RELEASE_NAME -n $NAMESPACE -o name)

for rollout in $rollouts; do
  kubectl argo rollouts promote $rollout -n $NAMESPACE
  echo "Promoted $rollout"
done

I know I can promote all rollouts using the above script. However, this method attempts to promote each rollout.
But what I really want is the feature to promote all rollouts belonging to a helm release at once in argo rollout.
I searched a lot but didn't find anything about this feature. If you know of any of these features, please let me know.
